# Create a custom front page for anonymous users

Tags: theming

I'm trying to create a custom front page for anonymous users, something like page--front-anonymous.tpl.php.

I could use the page--front.tpl.php template file, and check the role there, but I believe it is possible to create a separate template file for the front page when it is visited from anonymous users.

Any advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) hook you can put something along the lines of...

```
if ($vars['is_front'] && !$vars['logged_in']) {
   $vars['template_files'][]='page-front-anonymous'; // drupal 6
   $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='page_front_anonymous'; // drupal 7
}
```

which should work using the is_front and logged_in variables set by the various modules before you get to it.  if you are using a module, and don't want to rely on weight/execution order, you could do it with:

```
global $user;
if (drupal_is_front_page() && !$user->uid ) {
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how complicated your page is, but if all of you content is in blocks, you can adjust block visibility using the [block access module](http://drupal.org/project/block_access) on a per-role basis. I did that on a project - I ended up with one template file, but different pages based on whether or not someone was logged in.